# EC2 burstable instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to understand what does baseline performance means in this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html

Specifically the last section

Baseline Performance
The number of credits that an instance earns per hour can be expressed as a percentage of CPU utilization. It is known as the baseline performance, and sometimes just as the baseline. For example, a t3.nano instance, with two vCPUs, earns six credits per hour, resulting in a baseline performance of 5% (3/60 minutes) per vCPU. A t3.xlarge instance, with four vCPUs, earns 96 credits per hour, resulting in a baseline performance of 40% (24/60 minutes) per vCPU.

What does 5% per vcpu means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the t3.nano instance type baseline performance is 5% of vcpu. When cpu utilization is below 5% you earn cpu credits at the given rate (6 credits per hour). When you exceed this utilization rate, you will need spend accrued credits, if any. If you have 0 cpu credits accrued, EC2 will only allow the instance 5% cpu utilization.

Another way to think about it is that, for this instance type, you can only use 5% of the cpu before you cross into cpu burst accounting. Any use above 5% is subject to your CPU credit account for the instance.

Comment: Ah... CPU utilization! Thanks for the explanation Rodrigo! Now everything make sense for me...